# Performing regex_findall and split() on the same line

Tags: regex, split, ansible

Here is the output that  I'm trying to parse:

```
hostname#show bgp vrf vrfname summary | i 1.1
BGP Route Distinguisher: 1.1.1.1:0
BGP router identifier 1.1.1.1, local AS number 2222
1.1.1.3      0 64512  349608  316062   896772    0    0     2w4d          1
```

I have the following regex that succesfully matches just the last line. Now I need to split that line and view the last index. In this case it is "1", but I will want to fail if that value is "0".

```
- name: debug test
  debug:
    msg: "{{show_bgp_sessions.data | regex_findall('\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\s\\s.*')}}"
```

I tried adding a split in a couple different formats at the end of the "msg" line so that I can grab the last index to compare it in the failed_when statement:

```
msg: "{{show_bgp_sessions.data | regex_findall('\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\s\\s.*') | split(' ')}}"
```

But I'm getting the following error msg:

```
 "template error while templating string: no filter named 'split'. String:
```

I've also tried to use a few different forms of "ends_with" to verify the last index in the string as I've used that a lot in my python experience, but I can't get it to work in ansible.
I can't create a new task to parse the data and perform the split seperately because I need to run this verification through a loop.

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: Could you use a capturing and matching a digit starting from 1 group and somehow check the value? `\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s\s.*\b([1-9]\d*)$` https://regex101.com/r/Xh66TK/1

Comment: I tried to go down that grouping route, but couldn't get the syntax to work correctly. Your syntax above doesn't actually match the last value that I'm looking for based on the link you provided. It matches the entire line, but I need to validate the last index for each of those lines.

Comment: It captures the last digit in group 1, highlighted in green. That is the right value is it not?

Comment: I apologize, i didn't notice the green with glare on my screen. This might work, let me try it in my playbook. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

When you select the line, reverse the string, and split the first item. For example

```yaml
msg: "{{ (my_line|reverse).split()|first }}"
```

Comment: You are a life saviour... I did not find this thing with the parentheses anywhere. For future reference: output: "{{ output | default([]) + [ ''.join( (item, (item.split('_')[0]).split('some_string') | last ) ) ] }}"

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the regex provided by [@Thefourthbird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird) is a better solution.

But for your issue at hand, this is caused by the fact that there is indeed no filter `split` in Jinja, see the list there: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters.

The reason why there is no such a filter is simple: [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is a function of the Python `String`, and since Jinja is Python, you can just use it as is.

Also mind that, since `regex_findall` is meant for multiple matches, you'll have to select the first element of the list, for example, with the filter [`first`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#first).

So your message ends up being:

```yaml
msg: >-
  {{ 
    (
      show_bgp_sessions.data 
      | regex_findall('\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\s\\s.*') 
      | first
    ).split() 
  }}
```

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    show_bgp_sessions:
      data: |
        hostname#show bgp vrf vrfname summary | i 1.1
        BGP Route Distinguisher: 1.1.1.1:0
        BGP router identifier 1.1.1.1, local AS number 2222
        1.1.1.3      0 64512  349608  316062   896772    0    0     2w4d          1
        
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{ 
            (
              show_bgp_sessions.data 
              | regex_findall('\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\s\\s.*') 
              | first
            ).split() 
          }}
```

Gives the recap:

```
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "1.1.1.3",
        "0",
        "64512",
        "349608",
        "316062",
        "896772",
        "0",
        "0",
        "2w4d",
        "1"
    ]
}
```